# How much time does it take for new A-records to start working?

Tags: domain-name-system, shared-hosting, a-record

I created a subdomain pointing to another IP address with an A-record about two hours ago. When I try to ping, like pinging from different locations (using online services), I get `Unknown host:`.

The domain itself works fine, and it has the DNS records of the account, from where I am creating the A-record. I am on shared hosting.

How much time approximately can it take for a record to start working?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is multiple things here.
First you should check if your DNS provider has put it on their DNS servers yet.
Some providers can take a bit of time to do that. E.g.:

```
$ dig -t A newrecord.example.com @ns.yourprovider.com
```

If that responds correctly, that's good already.
When a client requests the new record for the first time, it will now get the correct response.

If a client requested the record already while it did not exist, then it is caching the negative result.
The time depends on your configuration, and can be checked at your SOA record:

```
$ dig -t SOA example.com +short
sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2014121047 7200 3600 1209600 3600
```

In that case it would be cached for 3600 seconds (last number in the SOA response).

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on your DNS server's [time to live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records) (TTL). This metric defines how long the ISPs cache the DNS entry for. If it's set for 24 hours for example, no ISP will try that DNS server for 24 hours, because it has a cache of it already.

Most TTLs are less than 24 hours however; see if you can find that metric in your configuration.

It could also be a separate DNS cache either on your PC, or somewhere else, so try accessing it on another network.

Comment: This doesn't apply here as he says he created a subdomain (a new A record). TTL only applies to existing entries being modified, not newer entries being created.

Comment: Ah okay, fair enough - I think you're right.

Comment: Not entirely, there is negative caching too.

Comment: @faker: Exactly. If you look up a non-existant host name and add it afterwards, the TTL will apply.

Comment: @faker My understanding was that negative TTL is not entirely enforced. However if it is applicable it should show up as the TTL on the top SOA record. Is this correct?

Comment: @Reaces: not sure what you mean be entirely enforced: Of course it will only affect clients which looked up the record while it did not exist. Yes, TTL of the SOA will apply there too.

Comment: @faker I meant that negative TTL is something that is not implemented consistently. As in some DNS servers will have a negative cache, others will not. I'm not entirely sure if this is true, it was told to me by a network engineer a few jobs ago so it might not be relevant anymore.

Comment: @Reaces: At least BIND and (IIRC) Windows Servers do it by default. But I'm sure there are servers out there that don't follow that RFC.

Answer (score 2):

You could set your local [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to point at the domain to test that everything is configured correctly. Are you sure your IP address is public facing?

If you are using Windows, your `hosts` file can be found in:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

You will need to add the following line:

```
{{IP address}}          {{domain}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#Resource_records) record and a record [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records). There are some time values for caching your DNS data. You can flush your DNS cache; it may help, but not always. At my DNS servers I use 15 minutes for caching.

Comment: This doesn't apply here as he says he created a subdomain (a new A record). TTL only applies to existing entries being modified, not newer entries being created.

Comment: generally hosting companies uses multiple dns servers. you edit one of master server. however queries are answered by slave servers. sync between them can take some time.